# Impact of increased correlation on $R^2$

Tags: correlation, multiple-regression

I would like to know if there is a mathematical expression linking the correlations between the predictors and the response variable and the coefficient of determination, $R^2$?

For this question, the predictors are all uncorrelated.

Intuitively I feel that an increase in the correlation between predictors and the response should improve model fit and hence yield a better $R^2$.

Answer (score 3):

Let $Y$ be response variable, $X_1, X_2,...,X_k$ be covariates, and $r_1, r_2, ..., r_k$ be the Pearson correlation coefficients between $X_1, X_2,...,X_k$ and $Y$. Then $$R^2 = \sum_{X_i \in \operatorname{Model}} r_i^2$$ given predictors are all orthogonal.

Comment: Thank you - do you have a source for the proof of this result?

Comment: See this link (first page). http://www.biostat.jhsph.edu/~iruczins/teaching/140.751/notes/ch8.pdf

Answer (score 0):

If you add one column of predictor values to the values in another predictor, the correlation increases between those columns. However, the goodness of fit, in terms of $R^2$, stays the same. So there is no formula that will link these, as the correlation can change independently of the fit.

Comment: I mean the correlation between the response and predictors, not between the predictors themselves